# ADO OleDB Connection String Not Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, ado

I have an ASP.NET C# application where I'd like to allow the user to retrieve data from both a Test environment and a Production environment. The app gives the user a dropdown with an option for either environment. The database connection is through a custom ADO provider that I use an OleDbConnection to query. The ADO was provided by a vendor, and I format a Connection String for each environment that looks like this:

```
string strProd = "Provider={ProviderName};Data Source={Production_Server};Password={Password};User ID={UserId}";
string strTest = "Provider={ProviderName};Data Source={Test_Server};Password={Password};User ID={UserId}";
```

Everything works fine the very first time that it connects. So, if I compile and deploy the application and the user first requests production data, it pulls data from the Production environment. However, when the user tries to pull data from the Test environment, the data retrieved again comes from the Production environment, even though the Test Environment's Connection String has been set.

Here's an example of how I'm retrieving the data - the applicable Connection String is passed to the function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  string strProd = "Provider={ProviderName};Data Source={Production_Server};Password={Password};User ID={UserId}";
  string strTest = "Provider={ProviderName};Data Source={Test_Server};Password={Password};User ID={UserId}";

  var prod = GetData(strProd); // returns Prod data
  var uat = GetData(strTest); // also returns Prod data ??

}

public DataTable GetData(string connStr) {
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top 10 field from table", conn);
  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(dt);
  return dt;
}
```

I'm positive that I'm passing the applicable Connection String, but it seems like the Data Source (and User Id/Password) are sticking with whatever was set the first time with this specific Provider. If I change the Provider to, for example, a Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider and read a CSV file, it does read that CSV file and correctly retrieves the CSV data. But then if I switch back to the custom Provider, it's still stuck on the first Connection String values, even if I set the Connection String to the other environment.

When I'm debugging and completely restart the application, if I connect to the Test environment first it will stick with the Test environment and won't update to Production, and if I connect to the Production environment first it will stick with the Production environment.  I've tried various ways to use the connection (using `conn.Open()`, `conn.Close()`, `conn.Dispose()`, etc.), but the data retrieved is always from the first attempt's Connection String.

I'm not ruling out that this is a bug with the custom ADO provider, but is there anything else that I can try? Is it possible that the values are being cached, and if so, is there a way to prevent that behavior? I'm stumped.

**Edit**: I separated the connections into separate classes per a suggestion by @jdweng - this did not solve the problem.

```
  public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      string connStr = string.Format("Provider=ProviderName;Data Source={0};Password=Password;User ID=UserId", ddlEnv.SelectedValue);
      GetEnvData envData = new GetEnvData();
      DataTable dt = envData.GetData(connStr);

    }
  }

  public class GetEnvData {
    public DataTable GetData(string connStr) {
      OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top 10 field from table", conn);
      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      return dt;
    }
  }
```

**Edit**: Adding Web.Config for inspection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>        
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The method you posted is "private" which I think is the clue.  What class is the code found?  You are not updating the instance of parent class which is causing the issue.

Comment: That's not the issue. It's all in the same class right now. The issue persists whether the method is private or public.

Comment: Exactly my point.  Changing the connection string is not changing the properties in the class.  Better to start with a fresh copy of the parent class.  Changing the properties is not calling all the methods in the constructor.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I tried putting Prod in one class and Test in another class altogether, and the same problem persists.

Comment: I added an edit to the end of the question to indicate that separating each environment into fresh classes does not solve the issue.

Comment: Why is the Page_Load method calling both databases?  Don't you want one or the other?  Why are the methods static?  You want one class/method with a parameter for the connection string and when you switch call the constructor for the class to destroy old connection and create new connection.  I'm thinking the connection pool is causing the current issue.

Comment: I'm just trying to write example code - it should be irrelevant whether the methods are static or how the parameters are being passed. I've updated the example to be exactly what you're describing, using a DropDownList control that indicates the Data Source. The user selects an environment and clicks a button. If they select Prod, it returns Prod data. If they then select Test, it still returns Prod data.

Comment: I've not experienced this behaviour before with classic ADO.NET. You may request disposal of the connection, but it is referenced in the Command object. What happens if you call Dispose via the SqlCommand/IDbCommand instead? Or the DataAdapter?

Comment: I've tried calling Dispose on the OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, and the OleDbDataAdapter. None of them gave me different results. I can only guess that the Provider is holding on to the first connection string, but I can't figure out if there's anything I can do to prevent that behavior.

Comment: This sounds like your connection is being cached unexpectedly in ASP.NET's cache and trying to change connStr in your button click handler doesn't really work. What happens if trying to separate the code more... perhaps a GetTestEnv() and GetUATEnv() that use string literals for the connection string, with button clicking just using the drop down list value to decide which to call?

Comment: I've tried that exact separation of putting the literal connection strings in separate methods and even separate classes. Unfortunately it still sticks.

Comment: OK Andy, what's your web.config like? Are you using any of the output or data caching options? And if you inspect your web-page response, what is in the Cache-Control header?

Comment: Nothing too crazy going on in the web.config. I edited it into the end of the question.

Comment: Cache-Control in the Request Headers is "no-cache" and in Response Headers is "private"

Comment: That all seems OK. You said "But then if I switch back to the custom Provider, it's still stuck on the first Connection String values, even if I set the Connection String to the other environment." makes me think it's provider related. What is the provider? Probably best to read more about its default behaviour.  Outside of that, I'm stumped too.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't disclose the provider - it's a custom built ADO provider from a vendor that my organization works with. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Gee, that is a mystery. It is possible that the custom "diver" you have keeps a connection open, perhaps based on the "sql", and if the "sql" is the SAME , then it uses the previous sql data for performance.

I would thus consider trying "different" sql for each try. If you send the exact same sql, it possible some kind of cache is used, and connection is ignored.

I would also wrap the code in a using which will close the conneciton, and ALSO dispose of the object correctly, and hence this:

```
public DataTable GetData(string connStr)
{
    DataTable dt = new Datatable();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr)) 
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select top 10 field from table", conn))
        {
           conn.open();
           dt.load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
     }
     return dt;
}
```